# Push log file to elastic using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, logstash, logstash-grok, grok

We have a error log file from Jmeter , that we need to be pushing to elastic using logstash

Here is the log file , we wanna be pushing the data from line 5 ,

```
 2021-05-14 20:32:49,822 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
2021-05-14 20:32:49,842 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
2021-05-14 20:32:49,843 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
2021-05-14 20:32:49,844 WARN o.a.j.JMeter: LogLevel: ERROR
2021-05-14 20:32:51,824 ERROR o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Http URL/API Test 1-4: ; response received: {"timestamp":"2021-05-14T14:32:51.688+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/healths"}
2021-05-14 20:32:51,824 ERROR o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Http URL/API Test 1-7: ; response received: {"timestamp":"2021-05-14T14:32:51.689+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/healths"}
2021-05-14 20:32:51,824 ERROR o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Http URL/API Test 1-20: ; response received: {"timestamp":"2021-05-14T14:32:51.850+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/healths"}
2021-05-14 20:32:51,824 ERROR o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: LEX 2-1: ; response received: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns3:systemContext xmlns:ns3="urn:abc.mon.utils.v1.context"><systemId>TREX</systemId><correlationId>hgfhjghj-c62dsfsdfdb-4aff-a871-8f32088943b3</correlationId></ns3:systemContext></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns3:retrieveStopPayResponse xmlns:ns3="urn:abc.tailhead.readyforcheck.processStopPay"><retrieveGagaPayResponse recordFound="false"><checkNumber/><stopPayDate/></retrieveGagaPayResponse></ns3:retrieveStopPayResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
2021-05-14 20:32:51,824 ERROR o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Http URL/API Test 1-5: ; response received: {"timestamp":"2021-05-14T14:32:51.687+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/healths"}
```

We want to be pushing data from line 4 specifically **PostProcessor: , response received:** to elastic. The below conf is just for response received:

here is the logstash conf

```
 if [type] == "errors"{​​​​​   
     grok {​​​​​
match => {​​​​​"message" => "%{​​​​​GREEDYDATA}​​​​​#*response received: %{​​​​​GREEDYDATA:error_message}​​​​​"}​​​​​
        }​​​​​
   }​​​​​
```

We get an error Grok parse failure **_grokparsefailure** when we try to push

Not sure what am I missing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:LogType} %{GREEDYDATA:data1} PostProcessor: %{GREEDYDATA:data2} ; response received: %{GREEDYDATA:responseRecd}
```

---

Example 1:

```
2021-05-14 20:32:51,824 ERROR o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: Http URL/API Test 1-4: ; response received: {"timestamp":"2021-05-14T14:32:51.688+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/healths"}
```

Output :

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "2021-05-14 20:32:51,824"
    ]
  ],
  "LogType": [
    [
      "ERROR"
    ]
  ],
  "data1": [
    [
      "o.a.j.e.J.JSR223"
    ]
  ],
  "data2": [
    [
      "Http URL/API Test 1-4:"
    ]
  ],
  "responseRecd": [
    [
      "{"timestamp":"2021-05-14T14:32:51.688+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/healths"}"
    ]
  ]
}
```

---

Example 2 :

```
2021-05-14 20:32:51,824 ERROR o.a.j.e.J.JSR223 PostProcessor: LEX 2-1: ; response received: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns3:systemContext xmlns:ns3="urn:abc.mon.utils.v1.context"><systemId>TREX</systemId><correlationId>hgfhjghj-c62dsfsdfdb-4aff-a871-8f32088943b3</correlationId></ns3:systemContext></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns3:retrieveStopPayResponse xmlns:ns3="urn:abc.tailhead.readyforcheck.processStopPay"><retrieveGagaPayResponse recordFound="false"><checkNumber/><stopPayDate/></retrieveGagaPayResponse></ns3:retrieveStopPayResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Output :

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "2021-05-14 20:32:51,824"
    ]
  ],
  "LogType": [
    [
      "ERROR"
    ]
  ],
  "data1": [
    [
      "o.a.j.e.J.JSR223"
    ]
  ],
  "data2": [
    [
      "LEX 2-1:"
    ]
  ],
  "responseRecd": [
    [
      "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns3:systemContext xmlns:ns3="urn:abc.mon.utils.v1.context"><systemId>TREX</systemId><correlationId>hgfhjghj-c62dsfsdfdb-4aff-a871-8f32088943b3</correlationId></ns3:systemContext></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns3:retrieveStopPayResponse xmlns:ns3="urn:abc.tailhead.readyforcheck.processStopPay"><retrieveGagaPayResponse recordFound="false"><checkNumber/><stopPayDate/></retrieveGagaPayResponse></ns3:retrieveStopPayResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
    ]
  ]
}
```

---

I have given dummy names as data1 and data2. You can separate them out further as per your needs.
Please use [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
^%{GREEDYDATA}ERROR%{GREEDYDATA}response received: %{GREEDYDATA:error_message}
```